# JPA | EclipseLink Left outer Join

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Just try to convert a SQL - Query to HQL / JPQL but it won't work and can not find any error in the statement.

```
// SQL - Statement (Gives all Entries from Entity1 joined with Entity2 if exist. 
// If Entity not exist the column has <Null> value )

SELECT e1.id, e2.id FROM Entity e1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Entity e2 
    ON e1.ID = e2.ENTITY1_ID AND e2.ID = '2' ORDER BY e1.ID DESC

Entity1{
...
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="entity1")
    private Set<Entity2> entities;
}

Entity2{
...
    @ManyToOne
    private Entity1 entity1;
}
```

Translated in JPQL:

```
SELECT e1.id, e2.id FROM Entity1 e1 LEFT JOIN Entity2 e2 
    ON e1.id = e2.entity1.id AND e2.xyz.id = '2'
```

Translation From JPQL:

```
SELECT t0.ID, t1.ID FROM Entity1 t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN Entity2 t1 
    ON ((t0.ID = t2.ID) AND (t1.XYZ_ID = ?)), Entity1 t2 WHERE (t2.ID = t1.Entity1_ID)
```

Exception:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'T2.ID' contains no table to any table in the FROM list is displayed in a join specification and is outside the scope of the same or in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement, is 'T2.ID' no column in the target table.
Error Code: 30000

Has anyone an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the mapped relationship?
"SELECT e1.id, e2.id FROM Entity1 e1 LEFT JOIN e1.entities e2 ON (e2.xyz.id = '2')"

Comment: Thanks @Chris. It work's perfekt.